In AIX (korn Shell) script I am executing in nohup getting failed with an error "Not a terminal" while on screen same script is working fine
In AIX script I am executing in nohup getting failed with an error "Not a terminal" while on screen same script is working fine..
I saved a script say it b.ksh, when I run it on screen
ksh -xv b.ksh > b.out

and it is working fine .
but when I am executing it in nohup or in cron it is failing .......
nohup ksh -xv b.ksh > b.out  &
error:
tail -100f b.out 
..
.....
.......
owner=orabq3
+ [ -f /usr/local/oracle/rman_log/ARCH/BQ3_backup.lck ]
+ touch /usr/local/oracle/rman_log/ARCH/BQ3_backup.lck
+ su - orabq3 -c script -q -c "export BACKUP_DIR=${BACKUP_DIR} && /usr/local/oracle/sap/SAParchive_nb.ksh sid=BQ3 >  ${BACKUP_DIR}/BQ3_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log 2>&1" /dev/null

Not a terminal       --------------- > this is error .
##########script ##########
#!/bin/ksh

# Define the list of databases and their respective owners
DB_LIST="BQ3:orabq3 CQ3:oracq3 DQ3:oradq3 IQ3:oraiq3 MQ3:oramq3 PQ3:orapq3 SQ3:orasq3"

# Define the location where you want to store the backup files
BACKUP_DIR="/usr/local/oracle/rman_log/ARCH"

#remove all lock file to handle rerun of failed backup and remove lock file
find "${BACKUP_DIR}" -type f -name '*.lck' -mtime +0 -exec rm {} \;



# Parse the string to extract database names and owners
for db_info in $DB_LIST
do
  # Extract database name and owner
  db=$(echo "$db_info" | cut -d ':' -f 1)
  owner=$(echo "$db_info" | cut -d ':' -f 2)

  # Check if the backup is already running for this database
  if [ -f "${BACKUP_DIR}/${db}_backup.lck" ]; then
    echo "Backup already running for $db, skipping"
  else
    # Create a lock file to indicate that the backup is running
    touch "${BACKUP_DIR}/${db}_backup.lck"

    # Switch user and execute backup script
 su - "$owner" -c  "/usr/local/oracle/sap/SAParchive_nb.ksh sid=$db > ${BACKUP_DIR}/${db}_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).log 2>&1"
     # Remove the lock file
    rm "${BACKUP_DIR}/${db}_backup.lck"
  fi
done

AIX server and I want this to run in background or in nohup.

The problem might be in /usr/local/oracle/sap/SAParchive_nb.ksh

try export PS4='$LINENO >' ; ksh -vx nohup ksh -xv b.ksh > b.out  &. The LINENO value will probably reset to 1 when /usr/local/oracle/sap/SAParchive_nb.ksh is call,ed and then revert when you're back in your main script. Good that you highlighted you're using AIX as it is a different beast with likely the older ksh. See if you can get ksh93 installed and use that (it won't fix this problem, probably). GOod luck.

Maybe su command ask for terminal. If you have sudo installed try with it
